# Rotation, translation or both.

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

[image]

the square is the same material throughout, equal mass distribution. In this case, will the object rotate, translate or both and why ? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please note that our homework policy asks you to show what you have done to solve this problem on your own.

Comment: This is not a homework, it is a personal question.

Comment: If the net forces are not zero then the center of mass is going to translate. If the net torques about the center of mass are not zero then the body is going to rotate. This question is a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/177417/392

Comment: Thank you for the reply, so the take away point is that if there is net force and net torque on an object at the same time, than there will be simultaneous translation and rotation. Is this correct ? So, in this example if the center of mass of this object is the center of the square, it will rotate about that point while also moving to the right ?