# Given two forces acting on two parts of an object, can we find the location of the resultant force in this problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

Suppose we have two objects $A$ and $B$ that are attached to each other. Suppose further there is a force $\vec{F}_{A}$ acting vertically on $A$ at $\vec{r}_{A}$ and there is a force $\vec{F}_{B}$ acting vertically acting on $B$ at $\vec{r}_{B}$. My main question is, can we combine these two forces into an equivalent resultant force $\vec{F}_{R}$ acting on the combined $A+B$ object at some position $\vec{r}_{R}$?

[This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282539) is relevant, but the replies there honestly don't resolve my specific quandary. I am dealing with a specific problem that I will outline in detail below.

---

Suppose we have two objects $A$ and $B$ as shown below that are attached to one another.

[image]

We assume both objects have a uniform depth $d$ in the $z$-direction. Now suppose one sub-object experiences a force $\vec{F}_{A} = F_{A}\vec{e}_{y}$ acting at $\vec{r}_{A}$, and the other sub-object experiences a force $\vec{F}_{B} = F_{B}\vec{e}_{y}$ acting at $\vec{r}_{B}$, and these forces are possibly different (maybe for concreteness one part is magnetic and the other is not). This is shown below with point $O$ being the origin of coordinates.

[image]

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are attached to each other, I want to find the resultant force $\vec{F}_{R}$ acting on $\vec{r}_{R}$, as shown below.

[image]

To do this, I assume that $\vec{F}_{R}$ alone and the pair of forces $\vec{F}_{A}$, $\vec{F}_{B}$ both result in the same change in momentum and the same change in angular momentum:

\begin{align*}
\vec{F}_{R} = \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt} = \vec{F}_{A} + \vec{F}_{B} \qquad\text{ and }\qquad \vec{\tau}_{R} = \frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \vec{\tau}_{A} + \vec{\tau}_{B}.
\end{align*}

The first equation easily gives us

$$ \vec{F}_{R} = (F_{A} + F_{B})\vec{e}_{y}. $$

The second equation gives

\begin{align*}
\vec{r}_{R}\times\vec{F}_{R} &= \vec{r}_{A}\times\vec{F}_{A} + \vec{r}_{B}\times\vec{F}_{B} \\
(r_{R, x}\cdot F_{R, y} - r_{R, y}\cdot 0) &= (r_{A, x}\cdot F_{A} - r_{A, y}\cdot 0) + (r_{B, x}\cdot F_{B} - r_{A, y}\cdot 0) \\
r_{R, x}F_{R, y} &= r_{A, x}F_{A} + r_{B, x}F_{B} \\
r_{R, x}(F_{A} + F_{B}) &= r_{A, x}F_{A} + r_{B, x}F_{B}.
\end{align*}

Now $F_{A}$, $F_{B}$, $r_{A, x}$, and $r_{B, x}$ are all known, so then we can solve for $r_{R, x}$ and obtain

$$ r_{R, x} = \frac{r_{A, x}F_{A} + r_{B, x}F_{B}}{F_{A} + F_{B}}. $$

Now the last part is that I need to find $r_{R, y}$, but thinking about torque (or moment of forces) simply does not give us any info about $r_{R, y}$. Is the problem here underdetermined? If not, how can we deduce $r_{R, y}$?

Comment: The torque of the vertical force around point O is independent of the x coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you're considering a rigid body, otherwise you can't replace a set of forces with an equivalent one, since the points of application of the forces matter.

For rigid bodies, you can find the resultant of the forces (vector sum of the forces acting on the rigid body) and the **line of action** of the resultant of the forces: the line of action has the direction of the resultant of the forces, and is the set of infinite number of points where you can apply the resultant.
So, when you look for the position of the point of application of the resultant force, the problem os underdetermined and you get an infinite number of solutions, corresponding to all the points of line of action.

Comment: This is very interesting. Do you know any good reference(s) (preferably book or paper) that talks about this more in-depth? I'd like to gain a deeper understanding about the line of action and how this applies to my problem.

Comment: Just think about it. If you move a force along it’s path, would it change any of the equations? Like force equations in each direction? Obviously not since the direction did not change. How about Moment equations? Also not since you use the cross product here which states you can move it along it’s path. So no equation changes and you can therefor move it freely. With more than 2 equations, you can also move the forces but add an additional moment.

Answer (score 1):

You are thrown away by your drawing. Your calculation (they are correct) just tell you the torque is independent of $r_{R, y}$. Since $\vec{F}_{R} = (F_{A} + F_{B})\vec{e}_{y}.$ any y component of $\vec{r}$  disappears in the cross product.
So draw  $\vec{r}$ horizontally.