# Is $τ=\frac{dL}{dt}$ valid in non-inertial frames of reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Similarly, is $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ valid in non-inertial frames? If not, then why? Surely, we can write $P=mv$ and $L=Iω$ in non-inertial frames.

Comment: @KP99 my book says that the torque equation is invalid, but the angular momentum equation is valid.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186317/

Comment: @KP99 I know how to calculate torques in non-inertial frames, I want to know why is it that $τ=dL/dt$ is invalid but $L=Iω$ is valid and whether this applies to translational motion.

Comment: In body fixed system is the angular momentum $~\dfrac{dL}{dt}=\dfrac{dL}{d\tau }+\omega \times L=\tau ~$ . The components of the torque is given in body system

Comment: See if you start from $\tau=r\times F$, then you see that $F$ can transform non-trivially under change of co-ordinate system, giving rise to certain "fictitious" terms, which is solely due to our choice of reference frame. E.g. [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force#:~:text=In%20physics%2C%20the%20Coriolis%20force,the%20motion%20of%20the%20object.)